# Parse multiple headers with same name

Tags: php, http-headers

I want to have properly implemented header parsing in my app. However, for example, let's have headers such as:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Foo: Bar
Foo: Baz
```

In this case, using `getallheaders()` returns only `Foo => Bar` and Baz value is dropped. Is there any other way to get all header values?

Comment: It sounds like this is dependent upon the SAPI that it is running under: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78844

Comment: Fair enough. Make it as an answer, please. I'll approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78844), this appears to be dependent upon which SAPI you are using for PHP. The basic question/statement was:

> If I make request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Forwarded: for=10.0.0.1,for=20.30.40.50;host=php.net,host=awesome.proxy.com;proto=https,proto=http
Forwarded: for=10.30.20.10;host=second.awesome.proxy.com;proto=http
```

> I get 3 different responses based on SAPI

- FPM only keeps last header
- php -s only keeps first header
- apache concatenates them with ,

And the response to the ticket was:

> The ability to get headers is highly dependent on the SAPI. Apache's works nicely, but php -s is just a quick development server that is not going to be suitable for all purposes.
>
> So really, the issue here is that php-fpm doesn't properly handle multiple headers. The HTTP spec requires that multiple headers only be allowed when their values can be combined into comma-separated lists, which means $_SERVER and getallheaders() are still sufficient.